# Creating a list of dictionaries with numerous key value pairs

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have multiple lists that I need to combine into a list of dictionaries with multiple key value pairs wherein the value could in itself contain a list - so for example:

```
namesIDs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
namesList = ['jacksparrow', 'aragron', 'harrypotter', 'bilbo', 'einstein']
address = ['addr1', 'addr2', 'addr3', 'addr4', 'addr5']
parentsIDs = [11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24, 31, 32, 33, 34, 41, 42, 43, 44, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56] 
parentsNames = ['Teague', 'MrsT', 'gPaT', 'gMaT', 'Arathorn', 'Gilraen', 'gPaAg', 'gMaAg', 'James', 'Lily', 'gPaHp', 'gMaHp', 'Bungo', 'Belladona', 'gPaB', 'gMaB', 'Herman', 'Pauline', 'Abraham', 'Helene', 'babyA', 'babyB']
```

The output I'm expecting is:

```
[{'nameIDs': 1, 'namesList': 'jacksparrow', 'address': 'addr1', 'parentsIDs': [11,12,13,14], 'parentsNames': ['Teague', 'MrsT', 'gPaT', 'gMaT']},
 {'nameIDs': 2, 'namesList': 'aragorn', 'address': 'addr2', 'parentsIDs': [21,22,23,24], 'parentsNames': ['Arathorn', 'Gilraen', 'gPaAg', 'gMaAg']},
 {'nameIDs': 3, 'namesList': 'harrypotter', 'address': 'addr3', 'parentsIDs': [31,32,33,34], 'parentsNames': ['James', 'Lily', 'gPaHp', 'gMaHp']},
 {'nameIDs': 4, 'namesList': 'bilbo', 'address': 'addr4', 'parentsIDs': [41,42,43,44], 'parentsNames': ['Bungo', 'Belladona', 'gPaB', 'gMaB']},
 {'nameIDs': 5, 'namesList': 'einstein', 'address': 'addr5', 'parentsIDs': [51,52,53,54,55,56], 'parentsNames': ['Bungo', 'Belladona', 'gPaB', 'gMaB', 'babyA', 'babyB']}
]
```

NOTICE the last item parentsIDs/parentsNames are LONGER than the rest.
I've tried using zip and dict comprehension but it doens't work/make sense to me.

```
>>> namesIDs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> namesList = ['jacksparrow', 'aragron', 'harrypotter', 'bilbo', 'einstein']
>>> [dict(zip(('NameID', 'Name'), item )) for item in namesList]
[{'NameID': 'j', 'Name': 'a'}, {'NameID': 'a', 'Name': 'r'}, {'NameID': 'h', 'Name': 'a'}, {'NameID': 'b', 'Name': 'i'}, {'NameID': 'e', 'Name': 'i'}]
```

**EDIT:**
PLEASE note that parentsIDs and parentsNames might be arbitrarily long. The first digit of parentsID determines which nameID a parentsID correspond to.

Comment: `zip` wont work because your last 2 lists length are not equal to other 3

Comment: Unless you know just how these lists were creates, it will be harder to put them back into dict form.

For example in this `[{'nameIDs': 1, 'namesList': 'jacksparrow', 'address': 'addr1', 'parentsIDs': [11,12,13,14], 'parentsNames': ['Teague', 'MrsT', 'gPaT', 'gMaT']},` how did you devices that `parentsIDs': [11,12,13,14]` is only those 4 values and not 5?

Comment: @Anu its because his total list length is 20 and he wants to divide it in 5 groups

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. I saw your solution and looks like it should do the trick

Comment: Note that a **critical** piece of information was left out in the question (and only clarified in the comments of the answers).  Since the number of parentsIDs (and parentNames) is arbitrarily long, there's no obvious way stated in the question to know which parentsID goes with which namesID (and it's NOT evenly divided as @Dahal commented).  Later comments have clarified that the **first** digit of the parentsID indicate what namesID it is associated with (i.e. 11-14 goes with 1, 21-24 goes with 2, etc).  This should have been stated in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list slicing inside the following list comprehension.

```
parentsIDsLists = [[]]
parentsNamesLists = [[]]
for i,j in zip(map(str, parentsIDs), parentsNames):
    if parentsIDsLists[-1] != [] and i[0] != parentsIDsLists[-1][-1][0]:
        parentsIDsLists.append([])
        parentsNamesLists.append([])
    parentsIDsLists[-1].append(i)
    parentsNamesLists[-1].append(j)

out = [dict(zip(('nameIDs', 'namesList', 'address', 'parentsIDs', 'parentsNames'), tpl[:-2]+(list(map(int,tpl[-2])),)+(tpl[-1],))) 
       for tpl in zip(namesIDs, namesList, address, parentsIDsLists, parentsNamesLists)]
```

Output:

```
[{'nameIDs': 1,
  'namesList': 'jacksparrow',
  'address': 'addr1',
  'parentsIDs': [11, 12, 13, 14],
  'parentsNames': ['Teague', 'MrsT', 'gPaT', 'gMaT']},
 {'nameIDs': 2,
  'namesList': 'aragron',
  'address': 'addr2',
  'parentsIDs': [21, 22, 23, 24],
  'parentsNames': ['Arathorn', 'Gilraen', 'gPaAg', 'gMaAg']},
 {'nameIDs': 3,
  'namesList': 'harrypotter',
  'address': 'addr3',
  'parentsIDs': [31, 32, 33, 34],
  'parentsNames': ['James', 'Lily', 'gPaHp', 'gMaHp']},
 {'nameIDs': 4,
  'namesList': 'bilbo',
  'address': 'addr4',
  'parentsIDs': [41, 42, 43, 44],
  'parentsNames': ['Bungo', 'Belladona', 'gPaB', 'gMaB']},
 {'nameIDs': 5,
  'namesList': 'einstein',
  'address': 'addr5',
  'parentsIDs': [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56],
  'parentsNames': ['Herman', 'Pauline', 'Abraham', 'Helene', 'babyA', 'babyB']}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create list of lists for last 2 lists and then use `zip` and `list_comprehension`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

namesIDs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
namesList = ['jacksparrow', 'aragron', 'harrypotter', 'bilbo', 'einstein']
address = ['addr1', 'addr2', 'addr3', 'addr4', 'addr5']
parentsNames = ['Teague', 'MrsT', 'gPaT', 'gMaT', 'Arathorn', 'Gilraen', 'gPaAg', 'gMaAg', 'James', 'Lily', 'gPaHp', 'gMaHp', 'Bungo', 'Belladona', 'gPaB', 'gMaB', 'Herman', 'Pauline', 'Abraham', 'Helene']
parentsIDs = [11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24, 31, 32, 33, 34, 41, 42, 43, 44, 51, 52, 53, 54] 


kv = {k:list(range(k*10, (k*10+10))) for k in namesIDs}
nd = defaultdict(list)
npnts = defaultdict(list)
for ele,pn in zip(parentsIDs, parentsNames):
  for k, v in kv.items():
    if ele in v:
      nd[k].append(ele)
      npnts[k].append(pn)
nd = dict(nd)
npnts = dict(npnts)

parentsIDs = [v for k,v in nd.items()]
parentsNames = [v for k,v in npnts.items()]

final_dict = [{"nameIDs":n,"namesList":nl, "address":ad, 'parentsIDs':pid, 'parentsNames':pn} for n,nl,ad,pid,pn in zip(namesIDs,namesList,address,parentsIDs,parentsNames)]

print(final_dict)
```

Comment: Dahl, your suggested solution gives the incorrect mapping of parentsIDs and parents Names as [[11, 12, 13, 14], [22, 23, 24, 31], [33, 34, 41, 42], [44, 51, 52, 53]] and not  [[11, 12, 13, 14], [21, 22, 23, 24], [31, 32, 33, 34], [41, 42, 43, 44]]. Furthermore I require any arbitrary number of elements in parentsNames/parentsIDs list such that zip might not work if the number does not match. Could you please review your answer

Comment: your solution only works if the length of elements of parentsIDs/parentsNames for all match, but not when one of the parentsIDs/parentsName has additional elements - my requirement is to satisfy any arbitrary number of elements in parentsIDs/parentsNames lists.

Comment: @KazSalvatore can you update your main question by adding what you want and by giving examples?

Comment: @KazSalvatore so you want 4 items for all lists. except the last list which can contain more or less than 4?

Comment: no, parentsIDs/parentsNames can have arbitrary length but by looking at the element (51) you know that it corresponds to the 5th element in dict and subsequently parentsNames at the same index as 51 also corresponds to the 5th element in dict.

Comment: if it was in range (60,70) would it be in 6th element?

Comment: If the first digit is 6x then 6th element, if 7x then  7th element

Comment: @KazSalvatore can parentIDs contain element like 100, 200?

Comment: yes the parentsIDs can contain higher numbers

Comment: @KazSalvatore just updated the whole answer, check it and inform me

Answer (score 0):

Your specific example presents a pattern of parentsIDs that could possibly be leveraged.  Each group is in a tens range (11..14, 21..24, ...) so we could use groupy to partition the parentsIDs list and islice over an iterator to group parentsNames with the same distribution:

```
from itertools import groupby,islice
d = [ {'nameIDs':ni, 'namesList':nl, 'address':ad,
       'parentIDs':pi, 'parentsNames':[*islice(pn,len(pi))] }
      for pn in [iter(parentsNames)]
      for ni,nl,ad,(pi,pi[:])
      in zip(namesIDs, namesList, address,
             groupby(parentsIDs,lambda i:[i//10]))]
```

Output:

```
[{'nameIDs': 1, 'namesList': 'jacksparrow', 'address': 'addr1', 'parentIDs': [11, 12, 13, 14], 'parentsNames': ['Teague', 'MrsT', 'gPaT', 'gMaT']},    
 {'nameIDs': 2, 'namesList': 'aragron', 'address': 'addr2', 'parentIDs': [21, 22, 23, 24], 'parentsNames': ['Arathorn', 'Gilraen', 'gPaAg', 'gMaAg']},    
 {'nameIDs': 3, 'namesList': 'harrypotter', 'address': 'addr3', 'parentIDs': [31, 32, 33, 34], 'parentsNames': ['James', 'Lily', 'gPaHp', 'gMaHp']},    
 {'nameIDs': 4, 'namesList': 'bilbo', 'address': 'addr4', 'parentIDs': [41, 42, 43, 44], 'parentsNames': ['Bungo', 'Belladona', 'gPaB', 'gMaB']},    
 {'nameIDs': 5, 'namesList': 'einstein', 'address': 'addr5', 'parentIDs': [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56], 'parentsNames': ['Herman', 'Pauline', 'Abraham', 'Helene', 'babyA', 'babyB']}]
```

*Obviously this is just simulated data and the actual parentsIDs may not be groupable based on `i//10` but, if you have any way to obtain a distinct grouping key from the parentsIDs values, this would allow you to form groupings of arbitrary sizes that correspond to the desired partitioning of these lists*

Comment: Thank you @Alain T. for your explanation, as a beginner trying hard to learn so a little explanation of your solution goes a long way!!  It just really sucks that as a new user I feel IF i missed out any 'critical' information the first time around - my question which is valid nonetheless has been down voted - its not like I have been rude to anyone or did not immediately respond. I'd always assumed people on stackoverflow would be welcoming/nicer especially if they're out here helping new coders - yet it appears its more about getting the answer in blazingly fast to get the most points.